# How can I remove a connection on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

How can I remove someone from my connections on LinkedIn?

Someone has been contacting people in my network saying I referred them. Not only is that annoying, it's unprofessional and makes me look bad. How can I remove this person? I've tried going to their profile but there is not a removal link anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Open your [Contacts](http://www.linkedin.com/connections) page.
2. Click Remove Connections underneath the search bar in the upper right. 
   [image]
3. Check the box next to the contact(s) you want to delete.
4. Click `Remove Connections` on the right.

[image]